# Remove a service? Windows-7

Tags: windows-7, services

Mysql was acting weird so i decided to delete the mysql data folder (but not install folder) and it corrupted. After trying to repair i simply uninstalled it from the control panels. The services are still showing up. How do i remove it?

How do i remove (any) services i dont want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services are located in the registry at the following location, **they do not always reflect the same name as they do in Windows Services**, so be careful what you delete or the operating system may no longer work or boot.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services

After you delete the appropriate mysql service, a reboot will be required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)" to find and delete any service (under the tab "Services"):

[image]